# Plotting data with nanosecond timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

The code below should create a butterfly graph, with bid bars in blue going up and ask bars in red going down. But when I plot it I just see two straight bars. I think it might be due to the extremely small timescale.

Any idea what's going on?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your DataFrame
data = {
    'event_timestamp': ['2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376',
                        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003',
                        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344'],
    'bid_size_1': [110.0, 30.0, 65.0, 96.0, 146.0, 146.0, 161.0, 111.0],
    'ask_size_1': [145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to datetime
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot bid_size_1 (blue bars going up)
plt.bar(df['event_timestamp'], df['bid_size_1'], color='blue')

# Plot ask_size_1 (red bars going down)
plt.bar(df['event_timestamp'], -df['ask_size_1'], color='red')

plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Size')
plt.title('Butterfly Chart')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

For further context, I need to display both at the microsecond level and at the second level, somehow show changes over time. Found it didn't work and simplified the problem to just showing data at the nanosecond level.

```
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
|        event_timestamp        | bid_size_1 | ask_size_1 |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659 |    110.0   |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248 |    30.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376 |    65.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780 |    96.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758 |    146.0   |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003 |    146.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034 |    161.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344 |    111.0   |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:33.831668204 |    76.0    |    125.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:34.300859840 |    61.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:35.250246888 |    70.0    |    145.0   |
| 2023-12-01 09:03:42.867285196 |    40.0    |    145.0   |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: It is the timestamp, see here for a possible fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53603536/7750891

Comment: That hasn't help my problem. It's like I need variable X axis that zooms in when microsecond level changes occur and zooms out when second level changes occur.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that matplotlib doesn't interpret pandas timestamps correctly. Use [pandas `plot` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your DataFrame
data = {
    'event_timestamp': ['2023-12-01 09:03:30.253234659', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253258248', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253284376',
                        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253286780', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253293758', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253299003',
                        '2023-12-01 09:03:30.253334034', '2023-12-01 09:03:30.259143344'],
    'bid_size_1': [110.0, 30.0, 65.0, 96.0, 146.0, 146.0, 161.0, 111.0],
    'ask_size_1': [145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 145.0, 125.0, 125.0, 125.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to datetime
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])
df['ask_size_1'] = -df['ask_size_1']

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot bid_size_1 (blue bars going up)
df.plot(x='event_timestamp', y='bid_size_1', color='blue', kind='bar', ax=ax)

# Plot ask_size_1 (red bars going down)
df.plot(x='event_timestamp', y='ask_size_1', color='red', kind='bar', ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel('Timestamp')
ax.set_ylabel('Size')
fig.suptitle('Butterfly Chart')
ax.grid(True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
fig.tight_layout()
#plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]